# How protected access modifier works in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have these classes:

```
package com.a;

public class A {
  protected String v="A";
}
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
package com.b;

import com.a.A;

public class B extends A {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new A().v);
  }
}
```

But `new A().v` doesn't compile.Why? I thought subclass has access to parent's variables even though it's in separate package.

Comment: Because you aren't doing `new B().v`

Comment: @Oleksandr. Interesting that the dupe even uses a similar attempt at a horizontal separator. Nice find.

Comment: @Oleksandr  Ok. I found answer to my question.Thanks